# I want to add multiple foreign key at single field in Django Model? Is it possible?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am building an Online Attendance Application in Django. In which the teacher initiates attendance and students give their responses.

Everything is great, but the problem occurs when one practical class is taken by more than one teacher at a time. I don't know how to reference multiple teacher `full_name` from `Teacher` model on a single `teacher` field in `Attendance` model.

The models are:

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)


class Attendance(models.Model):
    std_session = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="2023-24")
    att_date = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    std_class = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    unique_code = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    total_students = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

The view to save attendance data has a simple `form.save()` method.

Comment: With a `ManyToManyField`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use ManyToMany Relation but it may lead you to confusion in application layer (for example, when you're querying on your models).
It's better to know M2M relation well, then try it out.

after all,  you can put M2M relation between `Attendance` model and `Teacher` model.

```
teachers = models.ManyToManyField(Teacher)
```